# How to loop through UUID items

Tags: go

How do I loop through a slice composed of UUIDS? My values comes from db via `rows.Next()`

Here's how I'm appending my uuid values to my slice (really don't know if its proper)

```
type Images struct {
    image_id uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
}


var new_images []Images

for olds.Next() {
    olds.Scan(&oldimages.image_id)    
    new_images = append(new_images , Images{image_id: oldimages.image_id})

}
```

olds here is the rows im getting from `gorm Rows`

```
olds, err := db.Raw("SELECT images_received.image_id FROM old_pics").Rows()
defer olds.Close()
```

Heres the function in looping I was given but its for int i dont know how to use this for uuid:

```
func islice(s []int, n int, f func([]int)) {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i += n {
        var section []int
        if i > len(s)-n {
            section = s[i:]
        } else {
            section = s[i : i+n]
        }
        f(section)
    }
}
```

Any idea how I do this? Currently for uuid im using the `"github.com/satori/go.uuid"` lib

I got the function from another SO question, My goal is to iterate over the rows, but `rows.Next()` doesnt allow that I guess in order to do that I thought I needed to append them into a slice, so I can get them by fours.

Hence leading to this question.

Comment: mmmm... that `islice` function is kind of I don't know what is does well....let's says i have taste it at the playground: play.golang.org/p/V5a2Sf4EPl0 and don't get it... in any case if you need to loop over an slice of `[]Images`, use the `range` operator for iterate... i wonder if this code might help... https://play.golang.org/p/UWr8VVUEto9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace []int with []uuid.UUID everywhere in your islice function, including the parameter types. The functionality of islice() is not bound to []int if thats what your problem is.

Comment: thanks for your help earlier and thanks for this, however im getting

`cannot use new_images (type []Images) as type []uuid.UUID in argument to islice` error, when I tried this

Comment: No problem. You cannot pass in new_images because the Images type is not a uuid, the Images.image_id is the uuid. You need to make a different slice of only the Images.image_id then pass that one in

Comment: How do I do that in this case? I think my struct is right wit the datatype and I declared `new_images []Images` then throughout the iteration of rows I appended the `oldimages.image_id` to `Images.image_id` which is according to the example you gave, should become the slice that has been made throughout the iteration of rows and should be passed to the islice func? 

I tried stuff but it isnt working, still the same error

Comment: Eliminate the Images struct all together and just append the image_ids into a slice of their own. ie `var new_images []uuid.UUID` then just `new_images = append(new_images, oldimages.image_id)` instead of `new_images = append(new_images , Images{image_id: oldimages.image_id})`